# SQL группировка по двум полям с условием

Tags: php, mysql

помогите составить правильный sql запрос с условием для таблицы статистики посещения к примеру есть таблица

```
id         session_id                     user_id
1    80tfb91qrt3pks64q7bsto33ns2417gi       null
2    n6j26p6k9iul17iih04onnp8u6r5b193         2
3    h39gpcj5qc03l3ct7ie7b9e8018qmav0         2
4    i5kaeeqhom50iuov7dfgtcttgklcmv6f         3
5    sl8pfol4q7bsoue4i3v3pi2de5t5t2ll       null
```

которая хранит id сессии и id пользователя 
мне нужно выбрать все уникальные пользователи я пробую выбирать по user_id но мы видим что user_id не везде есть и в тех пробелах где user_id = null  мне нужно считать по сессиям но как правильно посчитать не знаю к примеру делаю так

```
select count(user_id)
from t1
group by user_id
```

но мне считает всех пользователей в том числе определяет пользователя c null
пробовал group by user_id, session_id   но мне считает все уникальные сессии

из моего примера должно получиться 4 уникальных пользователя
подскажите как правильно сделать выборку сгруппировать пользователей если нет то сессии?

Comment: `group by coalesce(user_id, session_id)`

Comment: – Mike да похоже но сейчас он мне выдает 4 строки http://prntscr.com/lu1bep а хотелось бы одним числом цифру 4

Comment: `select count(distinct coalesce(user_id, session_id)) from t1`. Без group by